# remDr$open() Unexpected Error when using RSelenium with phantomjs

Tags: r, phantomjs, rselenium

I am using the following code

```
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "phantomjs")
URL <-"http://www.soccer24.com/kosovo/superliga/results/#"
remDr$open()
```

I get the following error:

```
Error:   Summary: UnknownError
     Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
     class: java.lang.IllegalStateException
```

I don't know why am I getting the error?

My `sessionInfo()` result is below:

```
R version 3.0.3 (2014-03-06)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics grDevices utils datasets methods base     

other attached packages:
[1] R Selenium_1.3.5 RJSONIO_1.3-0 XML_3.98-1.1 RCurl_1.95-4.5 bitops_1.0-6   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] caTools_1.17.1 tools_3.0.3
```

And my java version is provided below for your reference:

```
system("java -version")
java version "1.7.0_55"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_55-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.55-b03, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't currently have the phantomjs.exe on your path.  More details can be found in the RSelenium "Saucelabs" vignette http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-saucelabs.html#id2a.

So download phantomjs from here: http://phantomjs.org/download.html and put the exe in your path.

Comment: Thank you.  I was able to make it work based on your links

Comment: I have the same error, but couldn't resolve it with this answer.

Comment: @Ansjovis86 are you sure that phantomjs is located somewhere on your path?

Comment: Yes it it currently in /opt/local/bin and I included that to $PATH. I downloaded the osx version 2.1.1. from phantoms.org and copied the binary into /opt/local/bin

Comment: And you're sure R recognizes that as part of the path? Have you checked the path from within R? Sometimes your path in a shell is different than your path in R